# Error accessing other groups files in apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions

I am using Cloud9 IDE on my server, which creates files with **default permission 640**. As a result when I try to open those file via HTTP, apache shows *permission denied error*.

When IDE is running as `root` user, files created belong to `root:root`. Also, when I see as what user is apache running, all its processes are shown to be running as `root` user.

I cannot understand why still it cannot access files. I know if I add apache's user to group of file owner, it will work. But, I don't know which user to add.

PS: I don't want to change permission of each file I create. I want less troubling solution.

Comment: which Linux flavor you are using redhat/ubuntu? could you please update the question

Answer (score 0):

In your main Apache config you should have two parameters called `User` and `Group`. With these you can specify what user, and what group Apache should run as.

Usually you should not run your httpd as `root` due to security issues. The normal case would be to have a specific user and group for the httpd. For example in `Debian` the httpd run as `www-data:www-data`.

Besides user and group you should check your configuration for the specific location. Typically this would be a `DocumentRoot`, `Directory` and/or `Location` parameter. Depending on your Apache version you might want to look into [Require (2.4)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) or [Allow (2.2)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow).

Hope it helps you forward.